# Dropdown element selection and JS call is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am having an HTML page where I have a dropdown and a button.

After selecting an element, button is pressed and I call function to take action as per following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Custom dropdown</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssdropdown/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Restart any service from here</h3>

<!--form method="post" action="example_new.php"-->
<span class="custom-dropdown">
    <select name="restart-component" id="restart-component">
        <option value=0>Data 1</option>
        <option value=1>Data 2</option>
    </select>
</span>

<button id="submit" name="submit" style="background-color:#1abc9c padding-left: 2cm;" onclick='goToRestart();'>Restart</button>

<p>Legend</p>
<br/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function goToRestart() {
        alert ("into js");
        var url;
        var location = document.getElementById("restart-component").selectedIndex;
        if (location == 1) {
            url = 'http://www.page.com/west';
        }
        else if (location == 2) {
            url = 'http://www.page.com/land';
        }
        #window.location.href=url;
        alert(url)
    }
</script>

    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1/prototype.js'></script>
        <script src="jsdropdown/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But my JavaScript function is never called. Am I missing something? Please help.

Comment: any errors in your browser console?

Comment: it would be really helpful if you can reproduce the issue in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: `type = 'button'` ? `#window.location.href` => `window.location.href`

Comment: It shows: Uncaught ReferenceError: goToRestart is not defined

Comment: Working fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpw3gaeb/ `selectedIndex` values can be 0 or 1...

Comment: It shows 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL' for the line #window.location.href. +1 for  Rayon Dabre

Comment: `#window` should just be `window`.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your function in an `onLoad()` or change your script as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
   // your page initialization code here
   // the DOM will be available here
  function goToRestart() {
    alert("into js");
    var url;
    var location = document.getElementById("restart-component").selectedIndex;
    if (location == 1) {
      url = 'http://www.page.com/west';
    } else if (location == 2) {
      url = 'http://www.page.com/land';
    }
    window.location.href = url;
    alert(url);
  }

})();
</script>
```

Comment: Still getting error: Uncaught ReferenceError: goToRestart is not defined

Comment: sorry, missed a `;` in the line `alert(url)`...please change it to `alert(url);`

Comment: Still getting same issue

Comment: It is showing the same issue. Uncaught ReferenceError: goToRestart is not defined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104906/discussion-between-lal-and-amandeep-singh).

Answer (score 0):

Try comment this line first

//#window.location.href=url;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function goToRestart() {
        alert ("into js");
        var url='empty';
        var location = document.getElementById("restart-component").selectedIndex;
        if (location == 1) {
            url = 'http://www.page.com/west';
        }
        else if (location == 2) {
            url = 'http://www.page.com/land';
        }
        //#window.location.href=url; //this line
        alert(url)
    }
</script>
```

Surely you will like to use "[try catch](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp)"

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error on your script. Try:

```
 function goToRestart() {
    alert("into js");
    var url;
    var location = document.getElementById("restart-component").selectedIndex;
    if (location == 0) {
        url = 'http://www.page.com/west';
    } else if (location == 1) {
        url = 'http://www.page.com/land';
    }
    //#window.location.href=url; line with syntax error on the character #
    window.location.href = url;
    alert(url);
```

And then change the calling for your function from `onclick='goToRestart();'` to just `onclick='goToRestart()'`

Hope it helps